# Question mark in URL for PHP variables makes the link broken. Any idea why?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-security

I don't know what changed in the past--this used to work:

Accessing a URL on my server like the following, doesn't work: http://www.domain.com/folder/file.php?variable=a&variable2=b

I'm getting a "Not found The requested address 406.shtml was not found on this server." message.

However, if I access this, it works:
http://www.domain.com/folder/file.php

Adding the question mark after file.php is what makes it break. I have never experienced a problem like this before. At first I thought that .htaccess had something to do with it, but I know as a fact that it hasn't been edited at all in the past.

Any ideas? I'm using CakePHP, but I doubt that has anything to do with it; this has worked before. All suggestions are welcome!

EDIT:
The /app/webroot .htaccess file has this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

As far as I know, this hasn't changed at all, and the URL worked with this. The .htaccess file right under /public_html/ contains this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on


   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did someone edit your webserver and enable rewriting?

Comment: The `406` points strongly to something in the server configuration (i.e. the central server config or a `.htaccess`). Or is there a proxy running?

Comment: @Viper_SB I'm not sure, but it could be =\ I'll ask my managed dedicated hosting to look at it. Hopefully they'll be able to do it. I don't have a proxy running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an error in your apache config.  It's attempting to give you the 406 error page, but can't find it.  If you fix that you may get a more informative error.

This link may help you with the root of the problem: http://urbangiraffe.com/2005/08/20/mysterious-406-error/

It could also be caused by `mod_security`.  If it's not your server you should ask your hosting provider.

Comment: Hey, I added that code to the .htaccess file to turn off mod_security, but that didn't solve the problem; I'm still getting the 406 problem. does that mean it's not mod_security? Any idea how to fix the 406 error page so that it could give me the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This problem with the question mark in the URL isn't happening on other domains, I realized. Only on this one that I'm working with. Does that mean it's not something to do with mod_security?

Comment: Got my host to fix it. Indeed it was a mod_security problem, and they fixed it quickly because I told them it had to do with mod_security. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

99.9% probability that this is being caused by a change in your htaccess file. Something is checking for a query string and redirecting to or trying to load a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Just added htaccess info to the original question. Care to check it?